# using case with count in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, subquery, case

I want to categorize the hit counts from the following query.i have tried but it gives me error. Can anyone help?

```
select case when (a.hit between 0 and 5) then 0
        when (a.hit between 6 and 10) then 1
        else 2,

    from    

    (select 
    distinct u.USER_NAME,
     r.VIEW_TYPE,
    B.ORG,

    g.CLUSTER
    ,Count(*) As HIT 
    from 
    dbo.Parameter p,
    dbo.Report r,
    dbo.User u,
    dbo.TimeStamp t,
    dbo.UserLog f,
    dbo.APP_USER B,
    (
        select CLUSTER,COUNTRY
from [dbo].[GEO]
union
select distinct CLUSTER,CLUSTER
from [dbo].[GEO]
    ) G
        where 
    p.PARAM_ID=f.PARAM_ID
    and r.REPORT_CUBE_ID=f.REPORT_ID
    and u.USER_NAME=f.USER_ID
    and r.VIEW_TYPE=f.ViewType
    AND T.TIME_STAMP_ID=F.[TIME STAMP_ID]
    AND u.EMAIL = B.EMAIL
    AND u.USER_NAME=B.USER_ID
    and p.GEO = G.COUNTRY
    and r.VIEW_TYPE='Industry View'

  group by CLUSTER,USER_NAME,VIEW_TYPE,b.ORG
  order by CLUSTER,USER_NAME,VIEW_TYPE,b.ORG) a
```

Comment: Did you actually read what the error was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess:

```
select case when (a.hit between 0 and 5) then 0
        when (a.hit between 6 and 10) then 1
        else 2
        END
from......
```

Raj

Comment: yes i read it.it was syntax error. i could not find out the problem with syntax. :( silly me.

Comment: @shishir_bindu If this was indeed the syntax error, could you please mark the answer as accepted? Wouldn't mind an upvote too :)